# How can I specify code contracts for existing framework (BCL) code?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

Code contracts work great until you have to add a bazillion `Contract.Assume(...)` for the results coming out of framework code. For instance, `MemoryStream.ToArray()` never returns a null array, as best as I can tell from looking at it in Reflector, but it's not documented as a contract, so I have to `Assume` it everywhere.

Is there a magical way to create a contract library for functions which already exist? I'm guessing that once you got a few dozen of the most commonly used framework functions contracted out, the warnings would get much more palatable.

Comment: It "never returns a null array" *today,* anyway. One of the things about a contract is you're not supposed to change it. The absence of such a contract *might* suggest that it *could* change. Maybe.

Comment: a fair point, but in the case of code contracts, I suspect it's because the contracts team just hasn't had time to add contracts everywhere. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/codecontracts/thread/d8e2c2ad-de37-42ef-a854-02052d821975, where one of the team members notes "We are working on filling in gaps as fast as we can, but it is mainly driven by us or you finding where important gaps are. Ideally, we would go systematically through the libraries and annotate them. At the moment we don't have the man power."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can directly. There are several things to do:

Request the contract be added in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/codecontracts/thread/d8e2c2ad-de37-42ef-a854-02052d821975) on the Code Contracts forums.

The suggested workaround by the Code Contracts team for now is to make a static method that assumes all the contracts you need. I find that this works best with an extension method:

```
static class Contracted
{
    byte[] ToArrayContracted(this MemoryStream s)
    {
        Contract.Requires(s != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<byte[]>() != null);

        var result = s.ToArray();
        Contract.Assume(result != null);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This way, you use `s.ToArrayContracted()` instead of `s.ToArray()`, and once the contracts *are* available on the type, you can just search-and-replace `ToArrayContracted` to `ToArray`.